# Spring-batch: Repeat steps in chunk oriented processing

Tags: spring-batch

I'm wondering whether it is possible, to configure a job in a way, that I could repeat several chunked-steps until the whole data is processed?
Background is, that I need to work on some real big data and while processing it, there's a risk of unwanted aborts. To prevent restarting from scratch over-and-over again, I'd like to do some partitioning of the data, that could be used to loop over the chunked steps.
Due to the given data, it is unfortunately not possible to make use of the spring-batch restartable-job feature to reach my goal.
My source database consists of several more-or-less loose connected tables, each of them is processed in its own step. So I have something like:

```
... omitting job-configuration ...
<batch:step="A" next="B">
   <batch:tasklet>
       <batch:chunk reader="readerA" writer="writerA" commit-interval="1000" />
   </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
<batch:step="B" next="C">
   <batch:tasklet>
       <batch:chunk reader="readerB" writer="writerB" commit-interval="5000" />
   </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
... some more steps with similar set-up...
```

Each reader has it's own SQL-Statement, to get the necessary data from the source-db and will write the result in another table of the target-db.

Now, my idea would be to, to adapt those SQLs in a way, that the data will be partitioned into some disjoint but consistent(*) parts, so that I could repeat the processing using the chunked steps as before. Maybe only adding some "parent-step" to control whether the loop has to be ended.

(*) By "disjoint but consistent" I mean, that although the data in the different steps is fetched from  different tables, there are dependencies. For example,  fetching the data to be processed for step B would do a join with table A, choosing only sets which were successfully processed.

Thanx for any advices!
/Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Since there are dependencies between tables, I don't think going parallel is appropriate. Going parallel makes sense when partitions are independent from each other.

Your current setup should allow you to restart your job from where it left off at two levels:

- In between steps: If the job fails at step B, step A would not be re-executed
- Within each step: If the job fails in the middle of step A, it will restart from the last successfully committed chunk of step A.

You need to make sure to use a persistent job repository and restart the **same** job instance in case of failure (using the same identifying job parameters as the previous run).